# Android Youtube api v3 showing only developer feeds

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am developing android YouTube app using google authentication, App showing my developer account feeds but when I access YouTube with different account, Feeds not showing, What is the problem? Is there any setting in google developer console?

//Authentication

```
public void googleLogin() {
        accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

        authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);
        if (authPreferences.getUser() != null
                && authPreferences.getToken() != null) {

            //doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
        } else {
            chooseAccount();
        }
    }

public void chooseAccount() {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }
public class AuthPreferences {

    private static final String KEY_USER = "user";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AuthPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context
                .getSharedPreferences("auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setToken(String password) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_USER, null);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_TOKEN, null);
    }
```

//for getting feeds I used sample code:
https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/akoscz/youtube